# ERROR: No matching distribution found for jaxlib

Tags: python, jax

When I tried to run my code in anaconda ,it showed up

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'jaxlib'`
and
`ModuleNotFoundError: jax requires jaxlib to be installed. See https://github.com/google/jax#installation for installation instructions.`

then I tried to install jaxlib by typing pip install jaxlib,it showed

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement jaxlib (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for jaxlib
```

my python version is 3.11.0

Plus,when I tried to import jax,it showed

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\BCS109110\chatgpt\re\rec\jax\jax\_src\lib\__init__.py", line 34, in <module>
    import jaxlib.version
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'jaxlib.version'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "D:\BCS109110\chatgpt\re\rec\jax\jax\__init__.py", line 35, in <module>
    from jax import config as _config_module
  File "D:\BCS109110\chatgpt\re\rec\jax\jax\config.py", line 17, in <module>
    from jax._src.config import config  # noqa: F401
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\BCS109110\chatgpt\re\rec\jax\jax\_src\config.py", line 24, in <module>
    from jax._src import lib
  File "D:\BCS109110\chatgpt\re\rec\jax\jax\_src\lib\__init__.py", line 38, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg) from err
ImportError: This version of jax requires jaxlib version >= 0.4.7.
```

Has anyone experienced the same problem?

Answer (score 0):

From the file paths in your error message, it looks like you're using a Windows computer. Unfortunately, the JAX team does not currently maintain jaxlib wheels for Windows (see JAX's [installation instructions](https://github.com/google/jax#installation) for details). The thread in [this issue](https://github.com/google/jax/issues/5795) has some suggestions that may work for you, but in general there's no officially supported way to install jax/jaxlib on Windows.

Comment: so is it possible to install jaxlib by downgrade the python version if still using windows system?

Comment: There is no officially-supported Windows jaxlib build for any Python version. But the thread above has posts from various users who have created Windows builds. If one of them requires an older Python version, then yes downgrading your Python and installing that may be an option.